# how to construct a square-integrable martingale by using standard stopping time argument?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I was reading a paper and the author said one can use the standard stopping time argument to show that the martingale is a square-integrable martingale. What does it mean? It is a paper talking about the solution of equation(2.1).
[image]

[image]
[image]
Condition (4.a) and the operator A is defined as below 
[image] 
  By the assumptions of the parameters, the part surrounded by a blue square is exactly $\int_0^t Af(x(s))ds$ in (4.4). So the question is how we make out a square-integrable martingale from the assumption of merely "martingale" in the condition. I searched the "standard stopping time argument" and find one related result which construct uniformly L1 from bounded L1. Is it helpful to my situation?
[image]
[image]
Many thanks!

Maybe I　should  hang the link on
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414909002166

**I guess "standard stopping time argument" should be some very common and popular method like Dykin-system.** But I do not know about it.

Comment: If you are trying to learn by having a book in contact with your head, you should be aware that osmosis occurs best in salt water, so you should first fill a bucket with salty water and soak the book in it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis   " When a cell is submerged in water, the water molecules pass through the cell membrane from an area of low solute concentration to high solute concentration. For example, if the cell is submerged in saltwater, water molecules move out of the cell. If a cell is submerged in freshwater, water molecules move into the cell. "

Comment: It seems like some additional context is needed here. Like, for example it seems like $x$ is the solution to some kind of SDE with a nonlocal term or whatever. What exactly is $x$?

Comment: Oh,yes! X is a solution to an SDE!@Shalop

Comment: I am not sure I understand your meaning. But Thank you for patience and I put the whole atricle here.@WillJagy

Comment: @Pearl Please make your question self-contained. For instance the author mentions equation (2.1) and condition (4.a)...  would be nice to tell us what he is talking about; otherwise it's pretty hard to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I remeber you answering my question last time.You are helpful! I have edited again to try to make it self-contained. But it has too many backgrounds. So I am still not sure whether I made it clear. Maybe it is not a proper question to be asked here. : (    @saz

Comment: Well, because of condition 4.a the function $Af$ is bounded, right? On the other hand, 4.a also implies that $X_t$ is square integrable and so $$M_t = X_t - \int_0^t Af(X_s) \, ds$$ is square integrable.

Comment: Pearl, the picture you chose for your profile shows a person with a book open on her face. Amusing.

Comment: But X(t) might not be integrable here. So I guess we just put a stopping time as the first hitting time and then it is a square-itegrable local martingale? @saz

Comment: AHA, now I get your point!  That is me and the book is an ancient Chinese poetry book. I am glad you like it. @WillJagy

Comment: @saz It is my fault not having mention that the function f  is bounded to make (4.4) a martingale. Here C_2(R) includes the bounded condition by the notation of the author. Sorry!

Comment: And I guess I should put locally square-integrable martingale instead of square-integrable local martingale in the last comment.